# how to store and access elasticsearch query in viewstate

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

I want store the filter query in viewstate variable and access that viewstate variable value after postback.

1) `ViewState["company"] = Query<company>.QueryString(q => q.Query(search));`

2) `var queryVar =ViewState["company"];`

3)

```
   var s = new SearchDescriptor<company>()
       .Index("search")
       .Type("company")
       .From(startRowNumber)
       .Size(10)
       .Query(q => queryVar);
```

Error: cannot implicitly convert type object to Nest.QueryContainer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`StateBag` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag(v=vs.110).aspx) that backs ViewState is not a strongly typed collection (backed by an `IDictionary` implementation) so you need to cast the object type returned from the indexer to the type that you know it to be. The error in your question indicates that this type should be a `Nest.QueryContainer`

```
public class company {}
var search = "my search";

ViewState["company"] = Query<company>.QueryString(q => q.Query(search));
var queryVar = (Nest.QueryContainer)ViewState["company"];

var s = new SearchDescriptor<company>()
   .Index("search")
   .Type("company")
   .From(startRowNumber)
   .Size(10)
   .Query(q => queryVar);
```